# "windowTitleBackgroundStyle" Doesn't Work on AlertDialog Title

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

**My Style**

```
<style name="myAlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

---

**My AlertDialog**

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext(), R.style.myAlertDialog);

builder.setTitle("Dialog Title");
builder.setMessage("This is message!");

builder.create().show();
```

---

My custom style has completely no effect. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searched so much online regarding this problem, I found out that `windowTitleBackgroundStyle` doesn't work, but `windowTitleStyle` works however, the result is not what I wanted:

```
<style name="myAlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/myDialogTitle</item>
</style>

<style name="myDialogTitle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title">
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

[image]

It looks like there are fixed paddings inside the whole `AlertDialog` layout. Besides that, `getResource().getIdentifier()` and `findViewById()` methods are not working so far. Therefore, `setCustomTitle()` becomes the only way to modify the title of `AlertDialog`.

---

**1. Creating a Custom Title Layout for AlertDialog**

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingStart="24dp"                         //following Material Design guideline
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingEnd="24dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Marvel Cinematic Universe"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"      //key point 1, using AlertDialog default text style
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

**2. Applying Custom Title Layout to AlertDialog Using "setCustomTitle()"**

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
View titleView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_title, null);

builder.setCustomTitle(titleView);                      //key point 2
builder.setMessage(R.string.main_marvel_info);
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);

builder.create().show();
```

---

[image]